# How to store a large image from a url in a chrome new-tab extension to use use as background even when offline

Tags: image, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that will replace the newtab page with an image from unsplash that will change daily. It will fetch a new image everyday and if the user is offline, it has to use the previous image. So I need a way to store this image for offline access as well as performance reasons. Note that the image can be very large (upto 4k).

My current implementation is to simply put the url in css `background: url(<url>)`, which fetches the image each time the user opens a newtab, which is very inefficient.

What would you do?

Comment: you could try to convert the image in base64 and store it in a persistent variable or in a indexedDB

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.